# .net core 3.1 & identity issue (claims nameidentifier has an id that doesn't match any user, while claims name is right)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm having an issue in an area of my website where i need to retrieve the user Id, i tried both by using the HttpContext.User and the injected IHttpContextAccessor, both give me an id that 1) doesn't match the user and 2) doesn't even exist in my database!

I also tried injecting a UserManager and calling GetUserId on it and that too gives me the wrong id (once again, no clue where from, it's not in the database). Calling GetUserAsync on it returns null.

I'm not using anything special nor fancy, the default page included with idendity core to log in, just a context that inherits from IdentityDbContext, and the login part works just fine as those pages are behind an Authorize tag and do force me to log in. If i was getting an error to begin with i could dig but i'm just getting an Id that seems to come from nowhere and am at a loss at where to look.

Here's what the claims look like when calling

```
HttpContext.User.Claims.ToList()

[0]: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: f478bf7a-1734-494c-aad6-0882ab24007f} <-- this id is not present in AspNetUsers table
[1]: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: EDITED OUT FOR PRIVACY} <-- my correct username (my email)
[2]: {AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp: EDITED OUT}
[3]: {http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: Administrator} <-- correctly finds my role too
```

Comment: Do you check the correct database  or modify the claims in application ?

Comment: @NanYu There is only 1 database, i don’t do anything to the claims, i let identity core do the login page and i don’t touch anything.

Comment: Then you confirmed that `f478bf7a-1734-494c-aad6-0882ab24007f` is not match the ID in AspNetUsers table ?really odd

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get the UserId

`using System.Security.Claims;`

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;`

---

`var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)this.User.Identity;`

`var claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);`

`var userId = claim.Value;`

Comment: It’s already what i’m doing but as i said the sent claims are wrong (wrong guid) so no matter how i retrieve it i get the same result (going through user on context, or httpcontextaccessor, or usermanager, it’s all the same and all gives the same guid. Also seems to be random as deleting the DB and restarting the site fixed it but i can’t bet on random in production and i should never get a wrong guid, much less one that isn’t even in the DB)

Comment: Hey! That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem for using this in `ExternalLoginCallback`:

```
var user = new SmileAppUser { UserName = email, Email = email };
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
```

Try to retrieve the user from the database to include the id in the claims with `SignInAsync`.